# How to get white bioluminescence?

Tags: bioluminescence

So I was wondering if it is possible to get white bioluminescence. Actually, I have heard dinoflagellates that produce blue light when there is some disturbance in the water. So I was wondering how to make this blue as white. If it works inside a flask, that is also fine because it should officially work.

So there are a few certain species of dinoflagellates that produce blue light when there is a disturbance in the oceans they live in. It is something like this:

[image]

Now, they regularly live in calm seas, and when there are small disturbances like waves or a person walking through them, they start glowing. This is one of the most stunning examples of bioluminescence.
I was planning to make use of these dinoflagellates. I was planning to put them in a black box, with a glass pane at the bottom. In the black box, there would be a tiny and slow motor to simulate the disturbances. Now, my only question is how to make these dinoflagellates glow white instead of blue. Are there any certain species of dinoflagellates that glow white that I am not aware of, or do I have to add any certain chemicals to the water to make them glow white (Please give a chemical that won't hurt the dinoflagellates), or is there any certain food to make them glow white, or should I add any changes to the glass pane to make the blue light look like white light?

BTW here is an image of the model I am talking about:

[image]

It's not perfect but is just a base model. Thanks in advance. If you need any other information, please comment.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122939/discussion-on-question-by-aster17-how-to-get-white-bioluminescence).